# The following modules are missing

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Всем привет! Прошу Вашей помощи. Возникла проблема с исходником при попытке его запуска. Буду откровенно честен, с UE4 я почти не работал. Все варианты, которые смог найти, я перепробовал. Буду весьма благодарен помощи. Необходимую информацию предоставлю. Спасибо.

[image: Ы]

Comment: будет неплохо если укажете что уже пробовали

Comment: Убирать плагины из сборки, добавлять их напрямую в корень UE4, собирать VS project files и т.д., в общем-то всё, что только можно. С исходником мне направлялись две рекомендации: надо редактировать сам UE4 и что никто с этим не разберётся. :)

Comment: Стоит ли ждать ответа?

Comment: честно говоря я не работал с данной средой, но я бы предложил поискать в каких вариантах можно получить ваши ресурсы, вот например https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/the-following-modules-are-missing-or-built-with-a-different-engine-version-with-a-new-project/343391 , может антивирус гробит все к примеру

Comment: я просто попытался добавить конкретики для тех отвечающих кто в этом понимает немного больше чем я :(

Comment: Я уже пробовал этот вариант с антивирусом. Спасибо, не помогло.

Comment: Кто-то сможет помочь?:)